# Assigning "id's" to mysql rows for use with an associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I've been making a search system for my website and I would like it to display a number of results with the data pulled from the mysql database. This caused a little problem, so I looked around the web for some help and found that you can actually use **mysql_fetch_array** or **mysql_fetch_assoc** to display the results. However, when I run the search form and the action page, my localhost server freezes and my computer starts to overheat (laptop).

How would I solve this?

Btw, I did try to use `while ($user = $mysql->tableCheckArray(_parameters_))` (as I found on some tutorials) but the same thing happened as stated above.

Here's my search code:

```
if (isset($_POST[search]) && !empty($_POST[search])){

$search = $_POST[search];

$mysql = new mysqlHandle;

$mysql->accessOpen('root', '', 'Portfolio', 'localhost');

// Sets $rows to number of entries with the 'Name' value of $search.

$rows = $mysql->tableCheck('*', stats, Name, $search, Portfolio);

echo '<div id="content">
    <div id="content_main">
        <h2>Search Results </h2>
        <br/><hr/><br/>';

if ($rows>0){

    // Sets the row's 'id' / entry number.

    $num = 1;

    while ($num<$rows){

        $user = $mysql->tableCheckArray('*', stats, Name, $search, Portfolio);

        echo $user[Name]."<br/>";
        echo $user[Image]."<br/>";
        echo $user[Age]."<br/>"."<br/>"."<br/>"."<hr/>"."<br/>";

        $num++;

    }

    /*
    while ($num<=$rows){

        $user = $mysql->tableCheckAssoc('*', stats, Name, $search, Portfolio);

        echo $user[Name][$num]."<br/>";
        echo $user[Image][$num]."<br/>";
        echo $user[Age][$num]."<br/>"."<br/>"."<hr/>"."<br/>";

        $num++


    }
    */

}else{

    echo "No users found";

}

echo '</div>
    </div>';

}
```

Here's my MySQL code:

```
function tableCheckAssoc($span, $table, $column, $value, $base){

    $this->span=$span;
    $this->table=$table;
    $this->column=$column;
    $this->value=$value;
    $this->database=$base;

    mysql_select_db($this->database);

    $this->query10="SELECT $this->span FROM $this->table WHERE $this->column = '$this->value'";
    $this->result10=mysql_query($this->query10) or die("<br/>"."Invalid $table CHECK query: " .mysql_error());

    return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result10);  

}

// Returns array.

function tableCheckArray($span, $table, $column, $value, $base){

    $this->span=$span;
    $this->table=$table;
    $this->column=$column;
    $this->value=$value;
    $this->database=$base;

    mysql_select_db($this->database);

    $this->query4="SELECT $this->span FROM $this->table WHERE $this->column = '$this->value'";
    $this->result4=mysql_query($this->query4) or die("<br/>"."Invalid $table CHECK query: " .mysql_error());

    return mysql_fetch_array($this->result4);       

}

// Returns number of rows.

function tableCheck($span, $table, $column, $value, $base){

    //accessOpen();

    $this->span=$span;
    $this->table=$table;
    $this->column=$column;
    $this->value=$value;
    $this->database=$base;

    mysql_select_db($this->database);

    $this->query="SELECT $this->span FROM $this->table WHERE $this->column = '$this->value'";
    $this->result=mysql_query($this->query) or die("Invalid $table CHECK query: " .mysql_error());

    return mysql_num_rows($this->result);

}
```

I would obviously like the 'Name', 'Image' and 'Age' values of the first queried row to be displayed and then the third et.c

Comment: Emoticons really shouldn't be a part of an SO question.

Comment: It freezes and overheats at the same time? Interesting. Anyway you're messing everything up quite spectacularly. I guess you don't have a clue what you're doing. Why don't you dig up some decent tutorials about using PHP and PDO (i.e. [this one](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)) and start from the beginning.

Comment: Is mysqlHandle a class? Please supply the whole class. I can't figure out the point of this.

Comment: @Bart I do have a clue what I'm doing, thanks for the feedback anyway. What exactly am I messing up quite spectacularly? Please tell me, I am dying to know, that's the only way of putting your comment to constructive use.

Comment: @VivaDaylight3 You're messing up what the first line of the accepted answer addresses. And you're not properly using strings and variables (i.e. use `'Name'` instead of `Name`, and `$POST['search']` instead of `$POST[search]`. And your way of executing SQL is very prone to SQL injection. And your function names do not describe what the functions do accurately. Basically, a mess. Fortunately all pretty easy to fix, so good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tableCheckArray() is returning the first matching record every time.  Every time you call it, you have to re-run the query and are passing it the same result set.

Instead have tableCheck() pass back the result.

```
function tableCheck($span, $table, $column, $value, $base){
    mysql_select_db($base);

    $sql = "SELECT $span FROM $table WHERE $column = '$value'";

    return mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid $table CHECK query: " .mysql_error());
}
```

Then you would run something like this:

```
$recs = tableCheck($span, $table, $column, $value, $base);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recs)){
    // print $row
}
```

The tableCheck functions are highly innefficient because they require you to keep running queries and they only ever return the first record.  Also, there is no point in `$this->span = $span`.  $span is already defined, so don't use more memory re-defining it.